# Convert csv File into Round Robin Database

Tags: csv, logging, raspberry-pi2, rrdtool

I am logging `Temp` and `Humidity` from a `DHT22` sensor on a `Raspberry Pi 2` running latest `Jessie`.

I did not know about the possibilities of `RRDtool` when starting the project so I chose to log everything in a `.csv` file called `DataLogger.csv`. 
The logging script is written an `python 3` executed every Minute with `cron`.
The Format looks like this:

```
2016-04-02 21:23    16.5    45.9
2016-04-02 21:24    16.5    45.9
2016-04-02 21:25    16.5    46.0
```

So it goes  `%Y-%M-%D %H:%M \t Temperature \t Humidity`

I am thinking about additionally log everything in Round Robin as well so my question is:

1. Can I load the `.csv` rows into a `RRDtool`  and
2. Can I use `update` from `RRDtool` to check the `.csv` file every Minute and update the Database

or do I habe to log the Data directly into the Database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RRDtool does not interact itself with csv files. But you can write a little script to read your existing csv files and feed them into RRDtool. Note that one call to the `update` function can take multiple datapoints in the `timestamp:temp:hum` format.

Once your existing data has been added to the rrd database, just add a call to the `update` function whenever you write to the csv file.

Answer (score 1):

As Tobi said, you will need to write your own script to parse your CSV fail and load the data into your new RRD file, as RRDtool does not itself have a function to do this.

You will need to work out the correct design for your RRD in advance; looking at your data, it seems to be every second and so you will need a 1sec Interval and probably your first RRA will need to be a 1cdp=1pdp.

You should also remember that data can only be added with time increasing; so, you can never add a datapoint for a timepoint earlier than the last update time.  Thus you would need to add your CSV data oldset point first and so on.